# I want to know the fruit name in Hundred Foot Journey

Tags: the-hundred-foot-journey

I just saw Hundred Foot Journey and in the starting scene, where a fruit seller sells a particular fruit to the main lead, saying "Sold, to the boy who knows". I want to know that fruits name. I know my question may sound a bit off topic, and I searched on Internet but couldn't found, kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched Google to find a reference to it, and found an on-line journal at wordpress that gives it a name: from [wordpress](https://conversationswithcharmaine.wordpress.com/2014/09/03/food-is-memories/):

*During my schooling years, we were a group of five girls who walked back and from school,  and every day, we would rush to the fruit seller’s cart to buy bimbli (Averrhoa bilimbi ), and “boras”, each one buying a packet, so that we could share our yummy treats, laughing and excitedly chatting, along the way, about the day’s events at school, and munching on our treats...*

It also carried a link to wikipedia for a [picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Averrhoa_bilimbi_fruit_by_Sugeesh.jpg/220px-Averrhoa_bilimbi_fruit_by_Sugeesh.jpg).

The wiki article says many of the parts are edible including the fruits, and the flowers. It can be served raw, cooked, and as ingredients in a number of dishes. Some parts of the tree have medicinal uses. Some other uses include a cleanser and a stain remover, and as dye.

Comment: Thanks man, I will see if get chance to get my hand on this fruit. :D